# Accessing function results

Tags: solidity

In the following example,

```
   contract Simple {
        function arithmetics(uint _a, uint _b) returns (uint o_sum, uint o_product) {
            o_sum = _a + _b;
            o_product = _a * _b;
        }
    }
```

1. How would one go about getting the result from arithmetics(5, 6)?
2. And how would you declare a variable holding the result?

Thank you.

Comment: The Mathematics is not working...using "blind poker"..The sum is 0..A= any number, even irrational (i.e. π) ..(A *B) - (A *B squared) = 0.......B=1.618...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is as follows:

```
var (sum, product) = arithmetics(5, 6);
```

hence, the results can be accessed via the sum and product variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the official docs aren't the greatest. In short you would need to compile the function, make sure the contract is mined and then call the function with `[contract].arithmetics.call(5,6)`

I wrote steps in more detail here about how I got this kind of simple function working (using this contract example is towards the end). Maybe it will help you: https://alanbuxton.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/first-steps-with-ethereum-private-networks-and-smart-contracts-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: There's no multiply function or namespace in the code given in my question.

Comment: Sorry, corrected function call. There are a number of steps to compile and mine your function, if you need assistance with those parts pls follow link and look towards bottom of the post

Comment: My question does not have compile or mine.

Comment: Ah I see you answered it yourself :)